# Javascript for loop, length isnt correct, length became the numbers of letters

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am echoing a while loop results from php into Javascript, Javascript is picking it up in AJAX  success function and displaying it in html.

The problem i am facing is, the number of times the for loop is repeating itself is the number of letters, characters, i am not sure why, i attached an image to display what i mean Thanks for your time![image]

I tried echoing it directly in php and echoing it in JSON format, both ways is creating the same problem.

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM list WHERE Listingid = '$Listingid' AND Status ='Bird'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
     $output[] = $row;
        }
        if (!empty($output)){

        echo json_encode( $output );}
        else{

            echo json_encode( [] );
        }
```

Javascript

```
 <script>

        function gup( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return null;
  else
    return results[1];
}
        var frank_param1 = gup( 'Listingid' );
        $("#display12").append(frank_param1);
        console.log(frank_param1)

            $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "interestedwaiting.php",
   data: {"data":frank_param1},
            success: function(data2){ 
                 for(var i=0; i<data2.length; i++) { 
                console.log(data2)


                 var html1 = "<div class=two> Listingid : " + data2[i] + "</div>";




        $('#display12').append(html1); 
            }}
         });





    </script>
```

Comment: either JSON.parse data2, or set the POST dataType to json

Comment: What are u trying to do here? `for(var i=0; i<data2.length; i++) { ` This is why it is repeating, because you told it to. If your response is `hello` it will repeat that for 5 times, because `hello.lenght is 5`

Comment: is `data2` is an array?

Comment: And `data2[i]` will print `h`, `e`, `l`, `l`, `o` because it is accesing the string positions.

Comment: Ahh ok, i will try to change the datatype to json and try again